# How to get the sum of two index in an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

Im making a code for an array that has a dynamic size and filling the array manually.Then, it will print. It will also ask for a number and finding the index that is equal to the two indexes.

I using codeblocks for this code. Id tried for loop to find the two indexes that is eqaul to the inputed number.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *array, int size) {
    printf("["); 
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        printf("%i,", array[i]);

    }
    if (size >= 1)
        printf("%i", array[size-1]); 
        printf("]\n");

    int num;
    printf("Enter number to be calculate: ");
    scanf("%d",num);

    for(int i= 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        if (array[i] + array[size-1] == num){
            printf("%d  %d", array[i],array[size-1]);
        }
        size--;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int count;
    int num;
    int sum;
    printf("Enter the size of the array:\n");
    scanf("%d", &count);

    int *array = malloc(count * sizeof(*array));
    if (!array) {
        printf("There was a problem you entered");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter the elements of the array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);

    printArray(array, count);
}
```

I expect the output:

Index 1 and 5 are eqaul to the inputed number. 
but it gives error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final loop in printArray is basically iterating through the array one element both upwards & downwards at the same time.

So, for n=6, if sum of either **(a[0]+a[5]),  (a[1]+a[4]) or (a[2]+a[3])** does not equal the required number , it would show up as unmatched.

This loop should be replaced by a nested loop so that inner loop iterates from j=i+1 to size-1 to allow check for **a[i]+a[j] == num**  for all possible permutations of array indexes.

Comment: Is this the right right code for this?                                                                        
     for(int i= 0; i < size - 1; i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j < size -1; j--){
            if (array[i] + array[j] == num){
                printf("%i %i", array[i],array[j]);
            }
        }
    }

Comment: That looks good. Just iterate i upto size -2 instead of size -1
`
for(int i=0; i<size-2;i++) {  
   for(int j=i+1; j< size-1; j++) {
      if(array[i] + array[j] == num) {
         printf("%i %i", array[i],array[j]);
      }
   }
}
`

Comment: Got it. thanks.. I got the correct indexes. May I know where to put if no index is match of what I inputed? I put inside the loop but it also print many times.

Comment: You could just define a bool variable outside the loop with default value as false. Set it to true inside the loop while printing the match happens. 

If the value is still false after the loop finishes, you can print statement saying 'no match found'.

In order to avoid printing many times, you can just break once the variable is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, the following bug is one of the problem -

```
scanf("%d",num);
```

should be -

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Comment: Thank you for that but still I cant add two indexes. I cant find the indexes that satisfy the inputed number.

Comment: Please mention the inputs you have tried. Expected and actual output.

Comment: If the two indexes added and the sum is equal to the inputed number, the two indexes will be print. If not, it will print no data match.

Comment: This link may help [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-two-unsorted-arrays-find-pairs-whose-sum-x/)